# How can I restart my Samsung S9 phone without the power button or any other physical button?

Tags: 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9

How can I restart my Samsung S9 phone without the power button or any other physical button, and without rooting my phone? I only want to use the tactile screen.

Comment: On unrooted phones there seems to be a possibility for a [device manager app to initiate a reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879426/150978) (on Android 7+). However in PlayStore there seem to be only apps that reboot using root permissions.

Comment: @Robert thanks interesting

Comment: If your power menu shows reboot option too, this can work: [restart Android phone when power button stopped working](//android.stackexchange.com/a/204821)